# rate of H-1B audits at universities

Tags: visa

An assistant professor I know at a leading US research university just received a visit from someone representing the "Fraud Detection and National Security" branch of USCIS, who was doing a random H-1B audit. The USCIS agent asked many detailed questions about the number of hours the professor spends in the classroom, the number of hours spent in office hours, salary, education, and so on, and took photos of the professor's office. The agent claimed that these random H-1B inspections happen regularly and are designed to find fraudulent applicants.

I have been in academia for over a decade and this is the first time anyone has told me of such a visit. The timing seems curious, to say the least. I am wondering if these random occasional visits have been happening for a long time, and it's just a coincidence that the one that I heard about occurs just as the new US government is beginning to implement radically different immigration policies, or if this is part of a new focus on H-1B visa holders. Any knowledge of the situation or further anecdotal evidence of recent visits might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the "Administrative Site Visit and Verification Program" ([USCIS site link](https://www.uscis.gov/about-us/directorates-and-program-offices/fraud-detection-and-national-security/administrative-site-visit-and-verification-program)) and it's not a response to the Trump administration; the site was last updated on 2014. Not every H1B applicant will be visited. So, chance is you'll find more "never heard of it" than "oh yeah."

And I highly doubt if there has been an increase in rate of visits in the last two weeks since the new presidency; this kind of measures seems too much of a finesse compared to what had been passed down from the executives.

Comment: Well that makes sense. It was initiated a good 7 years after I'd returned to my home country (Canada).